# Making sure div doesnt get bigger than the text - wrapping overflowing

Tags: css

I have a `div` that is being rendered from a data coming from the server.
the data sometimes contains a sequence of characters without any spacing that can be for example "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and "--------------------"
when these sequences get very long my `div` is rendered in a way that the `div` overcomes the scroll and boundaries and looks bad.

I have tried all solution with word break and word wraps and so on. but the issue is that if I fix the -----------------  (with SOH sigh for example) and it is being wrapped up perfectly then the other case is not good as the letter case ("xxxxxxxxxxx....") is cutting it as well as so regular words like current will be also spitted into 2 rows.

I need a solution for both IE and chrome

Here is the fiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/7vcw66cd/

Here's the code:

```css
.CIV-whatup{
  border-collapse:separate;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display:block;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal;
  height:34px;
  line-height:17px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
  margin-top:8px;
  min-height:15px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:0px;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  zoom:1;
  word-break: break-all; 
}
```

```html
<p class="CIV-whatup">!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
<p class="CIV-whatup">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p class="CIV-whatup">---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
<p class="CIV-whatup">
aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa</p>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements?  Using just `word-wrap: break-word;` will break words which are too long for their container but will wrap long words which are too big to fit in the remaining space in a line, but are shorter than the container in their own right. To me it seems using that would be the answer, but then I must be misunderstanding the requirements as I'm sure you've tried it.

Comment: yes it doesnt work with my dom structure - can you have a look on the jsfiddle and explain the problem?